# Is it possible to target a specific Arduino device with the CC3000 Wifi over the web?

Tags: arduino-uno

I've got my CC3000 Wifi shield and Arduino Uno working as intended using the several libraries, including the aRest.h library. In order for me to control the Arduino from anywhere across the web, I configured the port-forwarding settings on the router to address the Arduino via the routers ip address.

My question is this:  If I had a multiple Arduino modules/devices that relied on two way communication (client/server), how is the setup configuration automated for each device so that I could target a specific Arduino with regional data? I don't expect the end user to know how to access the router and configure port forwarding.

I hope this makes sense, I'm a newbie to the world of micro-controllers, but have had some success with progress as of late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make a simple way to setup the Wifi, when this job is done you connect via socket so a socket server ( python,node,etc... ) and this will avoid any port-forwarding.
You will not need to care about all this messy tasks, you can have as many as you want arduino in the same network and access from the internet.